# Trying to install new wm broke lightdm

Tags: debian, window-manager, display-manager

I am trying to install bspwm for my debian machine, and I've been following this [guide for dummies](https://github.com/windelicato/dotfiles/wiki/bspwm-for-dummies). So far, all the desktop environments and window managers that I've added on were all done through `apt-get install somewindowmanager` and their install scripts automatically told `lightdm` how to use them. However, `bspwm` I'm building from source.

I followed the guide as closely as possible:

1. Download source files and dependencies - this appears to have worked properly
2. Installation - `make`, `make install` seemed to work properly
3. Configuration copied example config files to `~/.config/` directories without any changes
4. Created `~/.xinitrc` file (guide made it sound like it should already exist?)
5. Additional display manager steps (probably where I screwed up):  The guide says "If you use a display manager (like Lightdm or kdm (this means you Ubuntu folks)) you'll probably want to copy the files provided in `contrib/lightdm` to their standard locations." I didn't know what "standard locations" was, but `contrib/lightdm` contained:

   1. `bspwm.desktop`
   2. `bspwm-session` (executable shell script)

The file `bspwm.desktop` had the line `Exec=/usr/bin/bspwm-session` so I concluded that the right place to put `bspwm-session` was in `/usr/bin`, and I grepped for `awesome.desktop` to conclude that  `dspwm.desktop` should go in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Following the guide: I tried `sudo xstart` and to my surprise an LXDE session started. I thought it might have just been that whatever config file wasn't loaded yet so I restarted my machine. The desktop greeter shows up as usual and hooray, an option for bspwm has been added! Unfortunately, when trying to log in I get a blank screen for 2 second and then sent back to the login screen. Moreover, this happens for ALL of my desktops, XFCE, LXDE, awesome, etc. all just go blank then return me to the login screen. If I start debian in recovery mode and then `xstart` I can still get an LXDE session going.

What do I do to fix this (and hopefully get bspwm running too)?

Comment: Let's start by removing the .xinitrc file. In fact, I think that might well fix it. Also, how did you install bspwm? Did you run `make install`? Also, how did you configure it?

Comment: I tried removing the .xinitrc file and the problem persists. I ran make install to install it (the guide didn't mention any other way to install)

Comment: Interesting development. I CAN log in as root from lightdm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with lightdm and this is how I solved:

- First follow [this guide](https://github.com/windelicato/dotfiles/wiki/bspwm-for-dummies)
- Then remember to run chmod +x /usr/bin/bspwm-session
  That's it i was missing the second part.